# How to enable system sounds in Lubuntu?

Tags: sound, lubuntu

I've seen outdated sources and posts on forums and other Q&A sites, but I haven't really found a working solution yet.

As of now, I'm on the premise that LXDE cannot work logon sounds.

Lubuntu has gone through some changes since the posts I've encountered, so I'm wondering if it's do-able now.

What can I do to get logon sounds, input/user-action sounds, and notification sounds in Lubuntu?

I'm running Lubuntu 17.04 as a VM.

I've made sure to check the settings available through the relevant menus, but nada.

EDIT:
To clarify even more: I can hear sounds when I play a media file or when I'm browsing through pages with audio content, but I'm not referring to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is possible on versions before 18.04 but one can setup a logon script and that will then work per user on the machine.

Quote:
"Log-in sound is just one example. Add ~/bin to your paths, make a script including all your start-up things inside it (you could even set their order with sleep INTERVAL), make it executable, and then add it to LXQt Session Settings → Autostart.

This is very flexible. For example, I’ve added /usr/bin/lxqt-notificationd & to such a script after removing it from LXQt module startup because I wanted it to have blurring with kwin and so, it should start a little later. And so on and so forth…"

Source:
https://forum.lxqt.org/t/will-lxqt-support-logon-sounds/396/8?u=thatrandomguy